# Image upload in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload an image much like a profile image to the project I am working with. I do not want multiple images that can be uploaded simultaneously. The previous image has to delete when a new image is uploaded.
Can anybody help me with this?

I am new to Laravel.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! :) Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and show us what you have tried so far and what problem you are facing. Showing your code may also help.

Comment: Does https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/filesystem#file-uploads help?

Comment: I did what i was supposed to thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

you can use these as reference.
This is for storing the data.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    //handle file upload
    if ($request->hasFile('partner_img')) {
        $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('partner_img')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('partner_img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $partner_img = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $request->file('partner_img')->move('images/partners', $partner_img);
        $input['partner_img'] = $partner_img;
    } else {
        $package_img = 'noimage.jpg';
    }


    $partner = $this->partnerRepository->create($input);

    Flash::success('Partner saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('partners.index'));
}
```

this is for updating.
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $partner = $this->partnerRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

```
    if (empty($partner)) {
        Flash::error('Partner not found');

        return redirect(route('partners.index'));
    }
    if ($request->hasFile('partner_img')) {
        $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('partner_img')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('partner_img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $new_partner_img = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $request->file('partner_img')->move('images/partners', $new_partner_img);
        Storage::delete('partners/'.$partner->partner_img);
        $input['partner_img']= $new_partner_img;
    }
    $partner = $this->partnerRepository->update($input, $id);

    Flash::success('Partner updated successfully.');

    return redirect(route('partners.index'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way along with some other fields. Now it is solved:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    request()->validate([

        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'file' => 'required|max:100000|mimes:doc,docx,pdf',
        'email' => 'required|email',

    ]);

    $peoples = People::find($request->id);
    $peoples->Name = $request->name;
    $peoples->Email = $request->email;
    $peoples->Address = $request->address;
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        if ($peoples->image) {
            File::delete(public_path($peoples->image));
        }
        $imageName = time() . '.' . request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->image->move(public_path('images/'), $imageName);
        $peoples->image = $imageName;
    }
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        if ($peoples->File) {
            File::delete(public_path($peoples->File));
        }
        $fileName = time() . '.' . request()->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->file->move(public_path('files/'), $fileName);
        $peoples->File = $fileName;
    }

    $peoples->update();
    $peoples->save();
}
```